# Integrals of a function which has finitely many discontinuities are not differentiable at the discontinuities

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I've tried solving an exercise stated below.

$$\text{Suppose that $f\in\mathcal R$ on $[a,b]$ and define $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}{f(t)dt}$.}\\\text{If $x$ is a point at which $f$ is not continuous, is it still possible that $F'(x)=f(x)$?}$$

So I approached in two ways. Let $k\in\{\text{discontinuities of $f$}\}$.

One is to show $F$ is continuous at $x=k$.

And the other is to show that $\lim\limits_{h\to0}\frac{F(k+h)-F(k)}{h}$ exists.

First step, $^\exists M\gt0$ satisfying $\vert f(x)\vert\leq M$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, since $f\in\mathcal R$.

(I'll assume that $f$ is defined at all the point on $[a,b]$.)

So, $\vert F(y)-F(x)\vert=\vert\int_{x}^{y}f\left(t\right)dt\vert\leq M\left(y-x\right)$ for $a\leq x\leq y\leq b$.

For any $\epsilon\gt0$, $\vert F(y)-F(x)\vert\lt\epsilon$ where $\vert y-x\vert\lt\delta=\epsilon/M$ .

Hence, the continuity of $F$ is clear.

Now I'm suffering to show that the second step is false.

For a jump discontinuity case, I've tried to

Consider $f(x)=
\begin{cases}
x^2/2+2, &\text{if $x\lt 2$} \\
x^2/2+6, &\text{if $x\geq 2$}
\end{cases}$.

In this case $k=2$. Then, $$\left\vert \frac{F(2+h)-F(2-h)}{2h}-f(2)\right\vert=\left\vert\frac{\int_{2-h}^{2}\left(t^2/2+2\right)dt+\int_{2}^{2+h}\left(t^2/2+6\right)dt}{2h}-8\right\vert\gt\epsilon=1\\\text{for any $0\lt h\lt\delta=g(\epsilon).$ (I'll skip the part of evaluating improper integrals.)}$$

Thus $F$ is not differentiable at $x=k$ where $k$ is a jump discontinuity, and it says roughly that $F$ is changing sharply at $x=k$, right?

But how about removable discontinuities? Any hint will be helpful.

Comment: For removable continuities, let $g$ be the function you get from removing the removable discontinuity. How is $\int_a^x g(t)\,dt$ related to $F$? But there are other types of discontinuity.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{R}$? The space of Riemann integrable functions?

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, I intended $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Then: it is possible that $F$ is differentiable at $x$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$ when $f$ has a discontinuity at $x$. But beginners are unlikely to find an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Consider the function $f(x) = \sin(1/x), x\ne 0, f(0)=0.$

Comment: Oh, thank you for answering @zhw. So, it means that $\vert\frac{F(0+h)-F(0-h)}{2h}\vert\leq\frac{\int_{-h}^{0}1dx+\int_{0}^{h}1dx}{2h}\gt\epsilon=1/2$?

Comment: I don't know what you're doing there. We see $f$ is discontinuous at $0$ and you need to show $F'(0) = 0 = f(0).$

Comment: I was totally wrong. $\left\vert\frac{F(h)-F(0)}{h}\right\vert\lt\delta/h=\epsilon$ where $\delta$ is the least upperbound of the length of the elements in a partition $P$ for $[0,h]$ and $\delta=min{h,h\epsilon}$?

Comment: Sorry, $\delta=\min\{h,h\epsilon\}$.

Comment: Anyway, thanks for answering :D